# For Each with SelectNodes not working

Tags: xml, vb.net

I have the following XML file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Transactions>
    <Transaction>
        <Datetime>2018-06-21T00:30:31</Datetime>
        <Operator>50</Operator>
        <Turn>5163</Turn>
        <Class>4</Class>
        <Type>1</Type>
        <Payments>
            <Methods>
                <Method>2</Method>
                <Currency>EUR</Moeda>
            </Methods>
        </Payments>
    </Transaction>
    <Transaction>
        <Datetime>2018-06-20T00:00:31</Datetime>
        <Operator>34</Operator>
        <Turn>3143</Turn>
        <Class>4</Class>
        <Type>1</Type>
        <Payments>
            <Methods>
                <Method>2</Method>
                <Currency>EUR</Currency>
            </Methods>
        </Payments>
    </Transaction>
</Transactions>
```

I want to go through each 'Transaction' and save the values of the nodes. The way I'm doing it, it goes into the second 'Transaction' but when I do a SingleNode it always shows me the value of the first.
I have the following code:

```vb
Dim oXML As New XmlDocument
Dim ArquivoXML As String = TextBox1.Text
oXML.Load(ArquivoXML)
Dim mgr As New XmlNamespaceManager(oXML.NameTable)
mgr.AddNamespace("df", oXML.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI)

For Each Transaction As XmlNode In oXML.SelectNodes("//df:Transaction", mgr)
   invoice.Operator = Transaction.SelectSingleNode("//df:Transaction", mgr).ChildNodes(1).InnerText
   invoice.PaymentMethod = Transaction.SelectSingleNode("//df:Methods", mgr).ChildNodes(0).InnerText
   invoice.Currency = Transaction.SelectSingleNode("//df:Methods", mgr).ChildNodes(1).InnerText
Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `//...` you do select *all* nodes with the given name. So in each iteration the expression is evaluated again and the result stays the same. To make use of the iteration you have to use relative paths to the current node:

```
For Each Transaction As XmlNode In     oXML.SelectNodes("/df:Transactions/df:Transaction", mgr)
   invoice.Operator      = Transaction.SelectSingleNode("df:Operator", mgr).ChildNodes(0).InnerText
   invoice.PaymentMethod = Transaction.SelectSingleNode("df:Payments/df:Methods/df:Method", mgr).ChildNodes(0).InnerText
   invoice.Currency      = Transaction.SelectSingleNode("df:Payments/df:Methods/df:Currency", mgr).ChildNodes(0).InnerText
Next
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Transaction.SelectSingleNode("//df:Transaction")
```

SelectSingleNode returns the first Node that matches the XPath query or null if no matching node is found. So what you are doing with that is always looking at the first node (in collection of nodes)

It's basically this:

```
For Each NODE In NodeCollection
    something = NodeCollection(1) 'instead of 1,2,3...n
Next
```

What you should do instead is:

```
Transaction.ChildNodes(1).InnerText 'transaction=NODE=NodeCollection(x)
```

When something is wrong you should breakpoint your code and inspect it.

I never worked with XML but I would do it like this (hopefully it works)

```
For Each Transaction As XmlNode In oXML.SelectNodes("//df:Transaction", mgr)
    invoice.Operator = Transaction.SelectSingleNode("./df:Operator", mgr).InnerText
    invoice.PaymentMethod = Transaction.SelectSingleNode(".//df:Method", mgr).InnerText
    invoice.Currency = Transaction.SelectSingleNode(".//df:Currency", mgr).InnerText
Next
```

EDIT: I get the following as output:

```
50
2
EUR
34
2
EUR
```

Are those expected values?

Comment: Doing this worked but only for simple nodes (as in your example). How to implement in the most complex nodes (Payments / Methods / Method)?

Comment: I didn't work with XML but it is similar to html, let me look. And remember that "//" means all, "/" = only children, ".// and ./" dot means from this "parent".

Comment: I updated my answer, also  <Currency>EUR</Moeda> that line doesn't look right.

Comment: There are multiple ways to do it, with loops, with children or with path selection, pick one. You can test and see which one is fastest, or pick the one that has the shortest code, it's up to you.

Comment: Mark your question as answered then.